# Por que o código não está executando o laço for, mesmo o compilador não mostrando erro?

Tags: java, array, loop

Estava fazendo um exercício sobre vetores, em que o objetivo era construir um programa que recebia um número `n` pelo *input* que definiria o tamanho do vetor, para depois receber, também por *input*, outros `n` números para serem alocados nesse vetor.

Após isso deve-se utilizar um método para encontrar o maior número entre esses últimos. Mas o problema que encontrei está justamente na maneira que encontrei para pegar e alocar esses `n` números no meu vetor.

Após testar meu programa várias vezes vi que o método é chamado, mas o laço `for`, que estava antes nem é iniciado. Realmente não sei o que pode ser.

[image: Print de quando rodei o programa; aparentemente o laço for não é executado]

O código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
//bubble sort array
public class EP6_1 {

    public static int maiorNumero(int array[]) {
        int resposta;
        for (int x = 0; x == array.length - 1; x++) {
            if (array[x] >= array[x+1]) {
                for ( int c = 0; c == array.length - 1; c++ ) { //c é o contador
                    int temp = array[c];
                    array[c] = array[c+1];
                    array[c+1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        resposta = array[array.length-1]; 
        return resposta ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner leitor = new Scanner(System.in);

        int lista[];

        System.out.println("Digite o tamanho do vetor"); //numero de elementos
        int N = leitor.nextInt();                        //da lista

        lista = new int[N];

        for (int i = 0; i == N - 1; i++) { //i é o contador
            System.out.println("teste");
            lista[i] = leitor.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>");
        System.out.println(maiorNumero(lista));

    }

}
```

Comment: Forneça o código de forma textual sempre, para que seja possivel nao somente visualizar, mas tambem execuar.

Comment: Antes de ver o código, e está difícil de ver como imagem do seu IDE (por que não cola o código aqui e facilita nossa vida?) você tem uma ideia errada do que é um compilador, e talvez do que seja um programa. Não mostra porque não tem nenhum erro que o compilador possa detectar e que impeça a compilação, mas tem um dos infintos erros que um código pode ter, e faz parte do trabalho do programador achar quando o co0mpilador não acha por você. Com o código eu posso ver se dá para dizer mais alguma coisa.

Comment: Perdão, essa é minha primeira postagem. Acabei de editar e colocar o código, mas acredito que também não ficou com a formatação desejada

Comment: Dicas para formatar o código: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: No for onde está escrito `i == N - 1` troque por `i <= N - 1`

Comment: Fazendo uma analogia - *bem* simplista - o compilador é como um "corretor ortográfico". Vc pode escrever um texto sem erros gramaticais - que o corretor considera correto - mas que só diz coisas sem sentido (e isso o corretor não detecta). Assim como pode escrever código sem erros de compilação (e portanto o compilador não reclama), mas com a lógica errada (não faz o que deveria).

Comment: @Bruno_SMR Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (terá pontuação suficiente logo depois de aceitar uma resposta).

Answer (score 7):

A condição do `for` é `i == N - 1`, portanto o laço executará sempre que essa condição for verdadeira. Ele não precisa executar se a condição de cara já for falsa. Logo antes você disse que `i` é igual a 0, portanto a condição só será verdadeira se o `N` for 1 (lógica básica matemática), em nenhuma outra situação isto é verdadeiro, então qualquer número que seja digitada e colocada em `N` que não seja 1 a condição será falsa e o laço não executará, nem uma vez sequer.

Provavelmente o que queria fazer seria algo assim:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/BasicIteration.cs).

Isso pelo menos seria o que todo mundo faz. Dessa forma será verdadeiro sempre que o valor de `i` for menor que `N`, portanto faz sentido para um contador, ele vai **de** 0 **até** o valor antes no número total. Só cuidado para não fazer `i < N - 1` porque isto não iria até o último item, ou fazer `i <= N` porque iria um além e daria erro. Poderia, mas não é ideal fazer `i <= N - 1`, está fazendo uma operação aritmética desnecessária e em algumas arquiteturas o `<=` é mais lento que o `<`.

Answer (score 0):

O erro está na linha 35

Substitua:

```
for (int i=0; i == N - 1; i++) {
```

por

```
for (int i=0; i < N; i++) {
```

A variável `i` está comparando com `N` e na verdade ela tem que ser menor que `N` (`i < N`).

Outra questão é que o laço inicia em 0 e vai até ele ser menor a variável `N`. A partir do momento que ele for verificar e `i` for igual a `N` ele não executará o bloco. Então se deixar o `i < N - 1;` ele vai contar sempre um menos.

Comment: Ah de fato, realmente é isso. Achava que colocando i == N - 1 faria a repetição até deixar i com esse valor. Obrigado

Comment: Não esqueça de marcar como resposta ;D

Comment: @Lucas não é muito legal induzir o autor a aceitar sua resposta, deixe que ele mesmo avalie qual das respostas é melhor, lembre-se de que o objetivo aqui não é aceites, é compartilhar conhecimento ;)

Comment: Eu só comentei para ele marcar como resposta pois dentre as duas respostas ele comentou só a minha, que por um acaso está recebendo votos negativos, tendo uma resposta mais objetiva e respondida antes. 
Até porque esta é a primeira postagem dele e acredito que ele nem saiba que tem como marcar como resposta, minha intenção não foi induzir que a minha resposta é melhor e sim lembra-lo que tem esta opção.

Comment: Ele *acha* que funcionou, mas fazendo `i < N - 1`, como vc sugeriu, o `for` vai percorrer um item a menos (e talvez ele não tenha percebido isso ainda). Então os negativos não são "por acaso". Já a outra resposta tem o código correto :-)

Comment: Pelo que ele apresentou ele quer que o usuário digite o número que irá definir o tamanho do vetor. Se o usuário digitar 5, como no exemplo que ele usou, o tamanho do vetor, iniciado em 0, vai ser 6 e não 5 como o usuário pediu. Acredito que não leram o que ele pediu...

Comment: `new int[N]` cria um array com N elementos. Usando `N` igual a 5, o array tem 5 elementos (índices de 0 a 4). Fazendo o `for` com `i < N - 1`, ele vai parar no índice 3, deixando o último elemento (índice 4) de fora.

Comment: Resumindo o que o @hkotsubo disse, seu codigo fará com que laço ignore o ultimo item, acho que você é que nao entendeu seu proprio codigo.